# Add applications (Ganglia, Impala, Hunk) to running EMR Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr, impala, ganglia

I created an EMR cluster but I forgot to add some applications that I'd like to play around with. It's a "long running" cluster so I cannot just create a new one.

How can I add `Ganglia`, `Impala`, and `Hunk` to a running cluster?

Also, is there anything else that needs to be done to have `HBase` report metrics to `Ganglia`?

Comment: Best direction is new cluster.  Hbase can be backed up to S3 (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hbase-backup-restore.html) and then restored on another cluster.  Or you can perform cluster to cluster HDFS copy between running clusters or copy to S3 and back for other data.  What is making it difficult to just replace the cluster?

Comment: It just feels like the wrong approach. It might not be difficult but it involves changing configuration of other components and might create downtime.

Comment: There is not automated way of installation. If you want, you can install it manually. But you have to perform this on all the nodes. Best option is to back up the data in S3 and launch a new cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
sudo yum install impala
sudo yum install impala-shell
```

([source](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_noncm_installation.html))

But I've never done it this way so no guarantees ;)